# Docusaurus server-side rendering could not render static page with path

Tags: docusaurus

I have a problem with displaying multiple API using Redocusaurus plugin

1. My nav dropdown looks like in the image
2. My Redocusaurus settings looks like in the image above
3. I keep my yml files in the folder apiConfigFiles

And locally everything working fine, but the problem appears when I make npm run build I have errors like in the image above...
Do you have any ideas how I can repair this??

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Getting this error.